# List Returns Json data have Error

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, json, model-view-controller

Am working in  have a problem that when List returns more data it will show an error. When the list return above 1000 records it shows "error 500 (Internal Server Error)".when the list return below 1000 records it works perfectly

My code is

```
function pageLoad() {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("RetrieveMSAccessLogin", "Student")',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',

                data: JSON.stringify({ AttendanceDateFrom: $("#AttendanceDateFrom").val(), AttendanceDateTo: $("#AttendanceDateTo").val() , EmpId : $('#EmpId').val() , EmployeeId : $('#EmployeeId').val() }),

                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function (data) {
                    successFunction(data);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert(Error);                        
                },
                async: true,
                processData: false
            });
    }
```

In c#

```
public ActionResult RetrieveMSAccessLogin(string AttendanceDateFrom, string AttendanceDateTo, string EmpId, string EmployeeId)
    {

        var msaccessdata = this.studentService.GetAllMSAccessData(AttendanceDateFrom, AttendanceDateTo, EmpId, EmployeeId);

        int ss = msaccessdata.Count();

        return Json(msaccessdata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're alerting the `Error` function.

That's exactly what the `Error` function looks like.

You probably want to look at the `result` parameter.

Comment: less than 1000 records returns it goes to success function ,when more than 1000 record returns it goes to error function ,what is the reason,am new to this please help me,i need a help

Comment: @user3622591: The error callback is trying to tell you what the error is, but you're ignoring it.  Look at the `result` parameter.

Comment: Look at the network tab to see what error your server is giving you.

Answer (score 1):

Replace:

```
            error: function (result) {
                alert(Error);                        
            },
```

with:

```
            error: function (result) {
                alert(result);                        
            },
```

This will alert the real error instead of the native code message you are seeing.  You can debug from there.